# Searching through PDF text and returning a snippet with Node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, pdf, elasticsearch, google-cloud-platform

I have about 2 million text searchable PDF files. I need to be able to search them for a user's query and return a snippet and a filename. The front-end is a Node.js React app.

Right now I'm able to use pdfjs-dist (https://github.com/mozilla/pdfjs-dist) to read the PDF content into a MySQL db. Then use fulltext MATCH ... AGAINST queries to search through the text. However, this is awkward and with 2 million PDFs is really slow. Also, new files are added regularly, so reading the PDFs into SQL is pretty resource intensive, too.

Is there a better solution? Is Elasticsearch a good solution for this?

The project is hosted on Google Cloud (App Engine & Cloud SQL). Is there a Google tool that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I would say that Elasticsearch is a great tool to index PDF and search in it later.

There is an [ingest attachment processor plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/ingest-attachment.html) that allows to extract data from the common formats (PDF, TXT, DOC, etc) and index it into Elasticsearch, so later it could be searchable.

Google Cloud have [Elasticsearch cluster plugin](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/elasticsearch?pli=1) which should make integration easier. Also there is a [Elasticsearch service in the Google Cloud](https://www.elastic.co/cloud/elasticsearch-service) which have massive support.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between the cluster plugin and the service?